# logout with onNavigationSelect

Tags: android, firebase

This is my code to logout to logInActivity. Though my fragments work, my logout button doesn't. What may be wrong?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference dbref;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent toMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogInActivity.class);
            toMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(toMain);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Get firebase instance - ignore FAB.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(mFirebaseAuth.getUid());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each, menu should be considered as top level destinations.Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

```
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_task)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't get you. please clear your problem

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman when i clicked the logout button, it doesn't go to the next activity

Comment: Where is your logout button? I can't see

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman its on this line: if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout) {

Answer (score 0):

You attach `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` with `NavigationView` which will override during default configuration of `setupWithNavController`. So attach your listener after configuring default settings. Check below code.

**Use**

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_task)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
        .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**Instead of**

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_task)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
        .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Comment: @G.L. Did you try the solution? If it will solve your problem then accept the answer and press upvote otherwise let me know the update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

implement `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in class

in onCreate function

```
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

add function in class

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            ...
            return true;
        }
        else {
            boolean handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
            if (handled)
                drawer.closeDrawer(navigationView);
            return handled;
        }

    }
```